# How to increment ID inside a <%= for %> view helper

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this in my code:

```
<%= for empresa <- @empresas do %>
    <%= render myProject.ComponentView, "smallPlacard.html",
        smallPlacard_id: "1",
        smallPlacard_class: "Company",
        smallPlacard_mainText: company.name
    %>
 <% end %>
```

I would like that the `smallPlacard_id` would be automatically incremented for each rendered element.
What's the best way of doing it in a Phoenix/functional way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Enum.with_index/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/2):

```
<%= for {empresa, id} <- Enum.with_index(@empresas) do %>
    <%= render myProject.ComponentView, "smallPlacard.html",
        smallPlacard_id: id + 1,
        smallPlacard_class: "Company",
        smallPlacard_mainText: company.name
    %>
 <% end %>
```

I have incremented by 1 in this example as the index is 0 based. If you need a string as before, use `"#{id + 1}"` instead.

Comment: `Enum.with_index` alternatively takes an `offset` as second argument, so you can use `Enum.with_index(@empresas, 1)` for a one-based index and replace `i+1` with just `i`. This is especially helpful if you need to use the index in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

works like a charm

```
 <%= for {item, id} <- Enum.with_index(@items) do %>
     <tr>
     <td><%= id + 1 %></td>
     </tr>
 <% end %>
```